# Database creation issue on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I need to create rails app with nginx and puma. I followed this guide: https://www.codeflow.site/fr/article/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04.

but this line doesn't work as expected:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

it drops the following error:

```
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
no implicit conversion of nil into String
Couldn't create '' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
[...]
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

Here is the content of my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

    test:
      <<: *default
      database: db/test.sqlite3
    
    production:
     <<: *default
     host: localhost
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: utf8
     database:
     pool: 5
     username: user
     password: mdp
```

Comment: Is that your database.yml file exactly, or is the indentation off in the question?

Comment: Yes, it's my database.yml

Comment: Well, then the indentation is all wrong, you must fix that.

Answer (score 1):

can you check config/database.yml file `production` `database` name

Must be this way

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

Answer (score 0):

All environments must use same database adapter

Sample database.yml file for PostgreSQL. Can you check configuration for this

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL_SIZE") { 15 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development


test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  username: user
  password: mdp
  database: myapp_production
```